# go の slice の cap が分からない

Tags: go

a tour of go を読み進めています。

```
var s []int
s = append(s, 0)
println(cap(s))
```

これが 2 になる理由が分かりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、length と capacity の違いに気を付けてください。`len(s)` は実際の `s` の長さ、`cap(s)` はスライス `s` を実装するために内部的に準備している配列の長さです。`cap(s)` がいくつになるかは実装依存であり `len(s)` 以上であれば良いので、あくまで仕様にしたがうだけなら「たまたまそういう実装だったから」というのが回答になります。

> The array underlying a slice may extend past the end of the slice. The *capacity* is a measure of that extent: it is the sum of the length of the slice and the length of the array beyond the slice; a slice of length up to that capacity can be created by *slicing* a new one from the original slice. The capacity of a slice `a` can be discovered using the built-in function `cap(a)`.
>
> https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types

ではどういう実装になっているのでしょうか。この回答が投稿された時点での Go の master ブランチの実装では、[この部分のコード](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/25a2b98f7a1454aac0d7d3072f74613ac0446630/src/runtime/slice.go#L76)が capacity を増やしています。特に以下のコードを読めば、今回のコードで `cap(s)` が `2` になっていた理由が分かります。

```go
newcap := old.cap
doublecap := newcap + newcap
if cap > doublecap {
    newcap = cap
} else {
    if old.len < 1024 {
        newcap = doublecap
    } else {
        // Check 0 < newcap to detect overflow
        // and prevent an infinite loop.
        for 0 < newcap && newcap < cap {
            newcap += newcap / 4
        }
        // Set newcap to the requested cap when
        // the newcap calculation overflowed.
        if newcap <= 0 {
            newcap = cap
        }
    }
}
```

というわけで Go コンパイラ自体の実装まで遡って回答すると「スライスの length が小さい場合、append したときの capacity は元の 2 倍以上になるように実装されてるから」となります。